# How to check system and all configurations after failed upgrade to 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

Last week i upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 but it failed along the way that i cannot reach the desktop, but i am able to enter the terminal(but without apt-get & purge commands) i tried dpkg --configure -a. but it still failed to do so. the cause of the failure was because of mysql-server-5.7. So, after lot of booting from previous kernel, ubuntu suddenly it was fixed. i can't recall what i did or how did it happen.

So, my question is how to check the system if everything was properly fixed? What command should i use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was a packaging issue, I'd run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If neither of those kick out any particularly ugly errors or warnings, I'd assume the problem had been fixed. If they do throw out errors, that's the basis for fixing this.

It's possible it wasn't a packaging issue, but rather an incompatibility with the new kernel. Again, this is something you can explore by checking everything is installed correctly and then moving back onto the latest kernel.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check this. i tried sudo apt-get update too before. the booting screen is still distorted. only the 4 dots appear. i hope this will be fixed by it.